# decorators - trying to understand this simple example

Tags: python, decorator

Basically I'm trying to implement a timing decorator:

```
def laptime(func):
    def inner(*args):
        start = time.time()
        r = func(*args)
        print time.time()-start
    return r

@laptime
def loop(a,b):
    for i in range(a,b):
        print (i)

loop(2, 1000)
```

I tried many ways of making it work, but they all returns funny results that I don't understand... I know there are multiple other questions on the topic on SO, but somehow they weren't helpful for me to get a better grasp of how this should be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A decorator function takes a function as an argument and returns a modified function. Your `laptime` doesn't return the modified function (`inner`), and it has the wrong indentation on `return r`.

Here's a repaired version. I've also changed it so it will run correctly on both Python 2 & Python 3.

```
import time

def laptime(func):
    def inner(*args):
        start = time.time()
        r = func(*args)
        print(time.time() - start)
        return r
    return inner

@laptime
def loop(a,b):
    for i in range(a,b):
        print(i)

loop(2, 10)
```

**output**

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0.000479936599731
```

---

The `@decorator` syntax can be a bit mysterious at first, but you do get used to it eventually. :)

Doing

```
@laptime
def loop(a,b):
    for i in range(a,b):
        print(i)
```

is completely equivalent to this:

```
def loop(a,b):
    for i in range(a,b):
        print(i)

loop = laptime(loop)
```

Comment: Yes I think I undestand a bit better now... Until next time ! thx